# Access this.$router in debounce function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to change the URL according to the input a user types.
The debounce function is working properly. But I can't seem to access the 'this' variable.

*'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation*

```js
searchbarPokemon: debounce(function (e: any) {
  this.$router.push(e.target.value);  
  console.log(e)
}, 1000)
```

Also the data send back by debounce is the last letter. Is it possible to get the full sentence?

Edit: found the full value at *e.target.value*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an arrow function to keep `this`' context:

```js
searchbarPokemon: debounce((e: any) => {
  this.$router.push(e.target.value);  
  console.log(e)
}, 1000)
```